# How can I make my own crop-image app visible to some other app that looks for crop-image apps?

Tags: android, gallery, crop, cross-application

I'm using someone's photo app which can send a photo to a cropper by opening up a list of cropping tools found on my device for me to choose. It currently shows "Gallery crop" and "Photos Crop". How can I add my self-made cropping app "Super crop" to show on this list? Would my super crop app have to be a root app like Gallery and Photos?

Comment: I guess you want your app seen in chooser, right ? So, maybe this help you.  http://www.developer.com/ws/android/getting-your-android-app-listed-in-the-app-chooser-for-various-activities.html

Comment: I don't think there's a crop action.  ACTION_EDIT for image/* maybe?

Comment: @AytekSökmen That's right. I'll check out the link